# yasnippet: jump at the beginning of inserted snippet

Tags: yasnippet

Is it possible to define that after inserting a snippet, the cursor will jump at the beginning of what has been inserted? It will make it even more fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: in the beginning
# key: in
# --
$0${1:default}
```

Comment: Exactly! Works like a charm!